# How to make collapsed work in mobile view of Bootstrap

Tags: android, html, twitter-bootstrap, kohana

I'm trying to make a mobile site using Kohana 3 and Bootstrap 3, but I got a problem. My collapsed menu isn't working. When I am trying to view the site on my Android Smartphone (4,3") and i press the menu button in the right top corner, it won't show the menu items. This is the code for my navigation bar;

http://pastebin.com/0bprF68u

(i suck with formatting the code in the  tags, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i'm dumb, loaded the javascript file of bootstrap before the javascript file of jQuery.